# How can I set hibernate-orm.database.generation and create-schemas in application.yaml

Tags: yaml, quarkus, quarkus-hibernate-orm

I'm new in Quarkus.
I am writing config file in yaml, but got stuck because of this config.

In Quarkus doc, I am seeing these config and I need to configure them.

```
quarkus.hibernate-orm.database.generation=drop-and-create
quarkus.hibernate-orm.database.generation.create-schemas=true
```

I'm not sure how can I make yaml same ?

```
quarkus:
  hibernate-orm:
    database:
      generation: drop-and-create # < this one is string and object at the same time...
        create-schemas: true
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `~`:

```yaml
quarkus:
  hibernate-orm:
    database:
      generation:
        ~: drop-and-create
        create-schemas: true
```

You can find more details in the documentation: [Configuration key conflicts](https://quarkus.io/guides/config-yaml#configuration-key-conflicts)