# Hibernate composite type for amount field

Tags: hibernate, kotlin, quarkus, quarkus-panache

Im trying to  map my custom postgres type to my hibernate entity, also I'm using Quarkus with kotlin and panache repository.

-> My postgres setup...

```sql
CREATE TYPE money_and_currency AS (amount integer, currency varchar(3));
CREATE TABLE example_table (
    "id" uuid,
    "amount" money_and_currency,
);
```

-> My Hibernate entity setup...

```kotlin
@Entity
@Table(name = "example_table")
class ScheduledTransactionEntity : PanacheEntityBase {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    @Column(columnDefinition = "uuid", updatable = false)

    @Column(nullable = false)
    @Embedded
    var amount: MoneyAndCurrency? = null
}
@Embeddable
data class MoneyAndCurrency(val amount: Int, val currency: String)
```

I got this error when I try to insert a new data into database:

> org.hibernate.exception.SQLGrammarException: could not execute statement [ERROR: column "currency" of relation "scheduled_transactions" does not exist

I tried also to add a columnDefinition="money_and_currency" to @Column annotation but nothing changed...

I just need to know how to properly map a composite custom type using hibernate.

Comment: error saying something is missing, if you run the code with [drop-create](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74470849/175554) that will trigger hibernate to create the tables for you, that will show what is missing in your setup.

Comment: I tried that and it didn't work because it created for some reason a int4 column type.

Comment: I fixed it by providing a @Struct(name = "money_and_currency")
When specified the type name it works.

Comment: you can answer the question with solution code, that would help someone else in the future. @caio-fernandes

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The entity is right but is missing a @Struct(name = "money_and_currency") annotation to tell hibernate what is the type declared in the database that hibernate should map to@Entity

```kotlin
@Table(name = "example_table")
class ScheduledTransactionEntity : PanacheEntityBase {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    @Column(columnDefinition = "uuid", updatable = false)

    @Column(nullable = false)
    @Embedded
    var amount: MoneyAndCurrency? = null
}
@Embeddable
@Struct(name = "money_and_currency")
data class MoneyAndCurrency(val amount: Int, val currency: String)
```